# Как я могу обновить состояние элемента меню кастомного Toolbar во время выполнения приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Я использую собственный `Toolbar`, определённый в `MainActivity.xml`, меню которого задано при помощи атрибута `menu`, а не путём переопределения метода `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)`, потому что у меня данный вариант реализации работать не захотел ни в какую (понятия не имею, с чем это может быть связано; я пытался следовать официальным гайдлайнам, но вышеназванный метод `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)` вообще не вызывался при запуске приложения).

Два из четырёх элементов меню моего тулбара по-умолчанию отключены и мне необходимо изменять этот параметр во время выполнения приложения. Варианты реализации необходимого мне поведения с использованием `onPrepareOptionsMenu(...)` и `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` не работают в моём случае, несмотря на присутствие вызова `setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar))` в методе `onCreate(...)` моей `Activity`. Было бы, конечно, удобно, если бы была возможность попросту использовать DataBinding Library, но, увы, не завезли (пока?).

Текущий код выглядит следующим образом.

#### MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.vo1d.app.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/file_name_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:autofillHints="filename"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/file_name_hint"
                android:inputType="textShortMessage"
                android:maxWidth="300dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:text="@{viewModel.fileName}"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/input_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:hint="@string/input_field_hint"
            android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine|text|textCapSentences|textAutoComplete"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@={viewModel.text}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.vo1d.app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;
    MainViewModel viewModel;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);

        TextInputEditText fileNameField = findViewById(R.id.file_name_field);
        fileNameField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.save_file_action).setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.save_file_action).setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

#### MainMenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/create_new_file_action"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_create_24"
        android:title="@string/create_new_file"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/open_file_action"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_folder_open_24"
        android:title="@string/open_file"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/save_file_action"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_save_24"
        android:title="@string/save_file"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

#### UPD:

Если говорить коротко: я пытаюсь добиться того, чтоб параметр `enabled` элемента `save_file_action` моего меню изменялся в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия текста в текстовом поле `file_name_field`.
Вызов `toolbar.invalidate()` тоже не помог достичь желаемого эффекта.

Comment: Не шибко понял что вы хотите сделать, но если меня память не подводит, у меню есть метод invalidate().

Comment: Если коротко, то делать активным один из пунктов меню, если присутствует текст в заголовочном текстовом поле. UPD: у меню, возвращаемого из Toolbar, нет подобного метода.

Comment: если говорить коротко - нужно искать причину, почему именно у вас не получается классическое решение, которое у всех работает, а не городить невероятные костыли и потом спрашивать, какими еще костылями их подпереть. больше читайте по теме, развивайтесь в правильном направлении, а не вот так вот - налепил что придется, да и так сойдет, ведь что то даже работает ..

Comment: @pavlofff использование атрибута app:menu у тулбара в разметке для задания ему меню — это костыль?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что ж, совет про `if (s.length() == 0)` был не лишним, но ничего больше мне не помогло.

Оказалось, что рабочим является самый прямолинейный подход (что странно, потому что сначала я пытался использовать и его, но тогда нужного мне эффекта достичь не удавалось):

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.length() == 0)
    {
        findViewById(R.id.save_file_action).setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
        findViewById(R.id.save_file_action).setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Остальной же код остался точно таким же.
Вот и всё. Надеюсь, это поможет кому-нибудь в дальнейшем, потому что для такой реализации, как у меня, рабочих ответов от других людей найти я так и не смог.

Comment: при каждом изменении текста получать заново вью по ид методом findViewById() - непозволительная роскошь. метод довольно ресурсозатратный, к тому же способ будет плодить кучу объектов, забивать память и прочий треш. После таких строчек у андроида и появляется репутация тормозного лагучего недоразумения. Получать все вью из разметки по его ид нужно один раз, обычно при создании активити в методе onCreate(), затем пользоваться сохраненной в переменной поля класса  вью.

Answer (score 1):

Меню можно извлечь меню без "системных" методов активити:

```
 toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.test_menu)
```

Эту строку нужно будет удалить:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Т.к. этот вызов отработает горозда позже onCreate() и перезапишет всё (тайтл, установленное меню и т.д.)

### UPD

Селектор - просто файл, описывает внешний вид компонента при разных состояниях (enabled, pressed и т.д.).

1) Цвет иконки (tint)
файл нужно поместить в res/color/file_name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="#673AB7" android:state_enabled="false" />
  <item android:color="#8BC34A" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

В ресурсе меню:

```
<item
    android:enabled="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
    android:title="Item"
    android:id="@+id/menuButton"
    app:iconTint="@color/file_name"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

2) Разные иконки при включеном/выключеном меню (файл res/drawable/file_name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_enabled" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>
```

В меню:

```
 <item
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/file_name"
        android:title="Item"
        android:id="@+id/menuButton"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

3) Селектор на текст item menu (если app:showAsAction="never"):
В стилях:

```
<style name="PopupTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/file_name</item>
</style>
```

В тулбаре:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/PopupTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

P.s. color это не values/color, а директория в /res.

Comment: Мне нужно не то что бы его извлечь или установить. Мне нужно у одного из item'ов установленного меню во время выполнения программы изменить параметр enabled с false на true при выполнении определённого условия.

Comment: Так у вас уже написан правильный код: toolbar.getMenu().findItem(R.id.save_file_action).setEnabled(true);. Это отключает/включает item меню. (что бы он изменялся визуально нужно написать селектор). Какой ещё результат вы ожидаете ?)

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, подробнее про селектор? Суть моей проблемы в том, что данный код не делает item доступным для клика (он всё равно остаётся неактивным, даже подсказка не всплывает).

Comment: @vo1d добавил примеры селекторов. Я думаю вы не правильно определяете пустоту строки: public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count). count - это количество изменяемых/измененных символов, насколько я помню.

Comment: @vo1d используйте if (s.length == 0)

Comment: Я это уже дебажил, setEnabled(...) успешно достигается и вызывается, но реакции никакой. Item как был при запуске неактивным, таким и оставался (как визуально, так и функционально).